# Cron for python script not able to find libraries installed in python virtual environment

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, importerror

Cron calling python script throws error of Module not found for Libraries that are installed and working fine when individually that Python script is executed in virtualenv on ssh

Python script runs in virtualend in ssh , Now trying to set cron for that script and add error log

error log

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

Want to libraries path to be set as per new python3.6 installation instead of python2.7 default path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron+virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs run in a different environment from your typical bash shell. You need to activate the virtualenv before running the cronjob.

Let's say that you have a python file called '/a/b/main.py' and a virtualenv '/a/b/env'. Here's an example cronjob to run the script every night at 12am (create with `crontab -e`):

```
0 0 * * * source /a/b/env/bin/activate && python /a/b/main.py
```

**GOTCHA**: cron runs by default in the `sh` shell, not `bash`. If you want to use `bash` you need to explicitly specify this (e.g. `/bin/bash ./something.sh`) or define the `SHELL` env var in your crontab (include `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top)